# Recent entries from each category in django model

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset, categories

I need to show in the template most recent entries from each category is the Instarama, Facebook, Twitter. Here my solution, but it does not work.

My get_queryset method but isn't working:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return super(OnlineManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_online=True).order_by('-date').annotate(Count('social_channel'))[:1]
```

This is my model:

```
class Social(models.Model):
    social_channel = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=SOCIAL_CHANNELS,
                                      default=SOCIAL_CHANNELS[0][0], blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, default='')
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.social_channel

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
```

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: @arcegk I get all posts or one, but I need last post per social channel

Comment: did you try a cycle?

Comment: @cycle? what is it?

Comment: A forloop for i in ....

Comment: try my answer and tell me if it is not working

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    super(OnlineManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_online=True).order_by('- id')annotate(Count('social_channel'))[‌​0]
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    query = super(OnlineManager, self).get_queryset()
    query = query.filter(is_online=True).order_by('social_channel', '-id').distinct('social_channel')
    return query
```

it should return the most recent entry for each `social_chanel`